# How can I show an active state (e.g. underline) ONLY for top-level navigation items on WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, woocommerce

The navigation menu consists of top-level items and one of those is called 'Shop'.

Within 'Shop', there are sub-level items showing in a drop-down menu. These items are product categories and when clicked on, the active CSS state (text-transform: underline) shows within the drop-down menu only and not on the 'Shop' button.

I need to have this active state indication show on 'Shop' for all drop-down items since it's pointless having the drop-down item underlined when the menu isn't visible. Totally breaks the UX.

I'm using WordPress and WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some code to your stylesheet with `current-menu-parent` selector. The code -

```
li.current-menu-parent > a{ text-decoration: underline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `current-menu-ancestor` class.

`.current-menu-ancestor > a { text-decoration: underline; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class name to only the top level items and style that one.

```
class Navigation_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    //if ( ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->$id_field ] ) ) {
        //$element->classes[] = 'has-dropdown';
    //}
    if( $depth == 0 ){
        $element->classes[] = 'top-level-item';
    }
    Walker_Nav_Menu::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
  }
}
```

Now there should be 'top-level-item' in the top level menu item class. And you can style that.